# Can't understand the difference between these parameters in GaussianHMM()

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

Can someone explain me the difference between the parameters `transmat_` and`transmat_prior`, when I [setup the model ( e.g. **`GaussianHMM()`** in `hmmlearn.hmm` )?](http://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hmmlearn.hmm.GaussianHMM)

```
class hmmlearn.hmm.GaussianHMM( n_components    =  1,
                                covariance_type = 'diag',
                                min_covar       =  0.001,
                                startprob_prior =  1.0,
                                transmat_prior  =  1.0,
                                means_prior     =  0,
                                means_weight    =  0,
                                covars_prior    =  0.01,
                                covars_weight   =  1,
                                algorithm       = 'viterbi',
                                random_state    =  None,
                                n_iter          = 10,
                                tol             =  0.01,
                                verbose         =  False,
                                params          = 'stmc',
                                init_params     = 'stmc'
                                )
```

Does the same explanation also hold for the parameters `startprob_prior` and `startbrob_`?

Comment: Can you post the documentation?

Comment: Only the latter is a parameter, the former is an attribute (same applies to startprob). Look up the basic concept of hmm's (it's somewhat an initial-guess; but theory might be more complex). (i'm also unsure about keeping the sklearn tag as this was removed a long time ago from sklearn; **edit** op removed sklearn-tag)

Comment: @wwii here is the documentation: http://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gaussianhmm

Comment: Neither `transmat_` nor `startbrob_ ` are parameters of `GaussianHMM`.

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding, `transmat_prior` is the initial value for the transition matrix that you can specify (it will be used for initializing the iterative parameter estimation algorithm). It is a parameter of the class.

`transmat_` is an attribute of an object of the class `GaussianHMM`, it gives the values of the transition matrix after training. It is not something you input yourself but a result of the estimation process.